# How to trigger ajax tabContainer resize in jQuery in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have ajax TabContainer in my App.

```
<asp:Panel ID="RightPanel" runat="server" CssClass="sizeForWrapper" style="width: 80%;float: right;">  

     <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" OnDemand="true"        
                AutoPostBack="false" TabStripPlacement="Top" ActiveTabIndex="0">

     <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanelDims" runat="server" HeaderText="Dimensions" Enabled="true"
                    ScrollBars="Auto" OnDemandMode="Once">

         <ContentTemplate>
           ...
         </ContentTemplate>

     </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
     </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
</asp:Panel>
```

And I have some background image for main content of the page. The problem is that content of the panel is resizeble, so it can grow up=), and I want my background grow up too.

Inside this panel I have some inputs, so I've tried to do this in jQuery:

```
$('input').bind('click',function () {
     $('.pageWrapper').height($('.sizeForWrapper').height() + 10);
});
```

`pageWrapper` is my background, and `sizeForWrapper` I added to `Panel`, but this works only for 1 click, so when I click multiple times it doesn't work.

My question is how to automatically trigger `sizeForWrapper` height change?

**Update**

The last thing that got into my head is:

```
    window.setInterval(function () {
        $('.pageWrapper').height($('.sizeForWrapper').height() + 10);
    }, 50);
```

But for me it looks weird, isn't? How bad is that?

**Finally**

I found my own way=) Will post it as answer later.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Upvotes appreciates if it helps somebody else=)

Comment: Are you creating new element on input click? if so the one which is newly created is not binding the click event.

Comment: Yes... So, how to fix it?

Comment: $('body').on('click', 'input', function(){});

Comment: Is pageWrapper parent of sizeForWrapper?

Comment: Why aren't we using `style="background-size:cover;background-image:url(whatever);"` for this?

Comment: It says there are compatibility issue with the plugin. In any case I think overflow:auto; on parent div can also solve the issue (unless I am misunderstanding the issue you are running into.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy has great plug-in

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Check this out=)